# How to create a pivotTable with panda in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code and I want to create a pivotTable using panda.

```
num_cols=ds_raw.dtypes.pipe(lambda x: x[x!='object']).index
ds = ds_raw.copy()

var_nom = ['DDA','DIRDEP','NSF','SAV','ATM','CD','IRA','LOC','INV','ILS','MM','MTG','CC','SDB','HMOWN','MOVED','INAREA']

for x in num_cols:
    imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
  `hola`  imp.fit(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))
    ds[x] = imp.transform(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show your input and output DataFrame

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html